# Maximo: Change work order status by clicking URL

Tags: web-services, url, gis, integration, maximo

**Background:**

I have 10,000 sidewalks that get inspected every year by foot (using mobile devices). The sidewalks have inspection work orders that are generated by PMs.

My users need to set the inspection work orders to `complete` as they walk the sidewalks. I think the best way to do this would be to:

1. Walk up to the sidewalk; the map would pan to their GPS location.
2. At their GPS location, the users would click the applicable sidewalk work order.
3. The action of clicking the work order would set the inspection workorder to complete.

*Unfortunately, it is my understanding that there aren't any Maximo products that can do this effectively. My organization has purchased Spatial, Linear, and Anywhere, but I don't think any of those add-ons can do what I've described.*

---

**Question:**

I might be able to solve this by creating an ESRI web map that shows the work orders in a layer.

The layer would have a **calculated URL** that, when clicked, would send a request to a Maximo web service, setting the work order to complete.

[image]

---

**Is it possible to change a work order status via a URL?**

*Maximo 7.6.1.1*

Comment: Assuming you have authentication happening via SSO or something, yes, this should be possible via Maximo's RESTful API.

Comment: Have you tried hitting an Object Structure based on `WORKORDER` with `statusiface`, `np_statusmemo` and `status` via a REST url with an `_action=Change`?

Answer (score 1):

A few questions - Does the ESRI map know what the WONUM is on the maximo side? If so- you can use the rest API, send a patch and be done with it. I'd write some sort of proxy or queuing mechanism in between the ESRI client and the Maximo Client to enable some sort of intermediary that you can manage.

POST /oslc/os/workorder/{rest id for the workorder}
x-method-override: PATCH
properties:*

{
    “Status”:”COMPLETE”,
    “description”:”Setting complete by user XXXXXX”
}

Any more questions and feel free to DM me - I work directly with Maximo and Mobile, and think our use-cases aren't that far off.